# How do I provide for multiple crops of the same image in a theme?

Tags: theme-development, mobile, header-image

I've been working on a Wordpress theme (my first, actually) and the design includes a header image.

However, the header is extremely wide and thus is really small when adapted to a phone layout.

How would I allow for multiple crops of the same header image, so that I could have one wide crop for the desktop layout and one more squarish crop for the phone layout?

Comment: The ad_image_size will give you a smaller image that links to a larger one, but I don't think that's what your asking for. I believe your wanting a "responsive design". Here is a very simple demo and short tutorial that helped me out quite a bit: http://verekia.com/initializr/responsive-template

Comment: @JeremyJared Yes, the design I'm building is indeed responsive. I'm asking how I can get a second crop setting. Whenever it asks for a crop it only asks once and (seemingly) randomly crops the second one.

Answer (score 2):

The [`add_image_size`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_image_size) can do that for you.